# Not able to Start td-agent as root user

Tags: fluentd, td-agent

I am new to  td-agent conf .I want to start td-agent as root user,I modified user and group in the /etc/init.d/td-agent as root .Ultimately systemctl want  to do start and stop the service .But still **ps -ef |grep td-agent** shows as td-agent user.

Please provide your inputs.

I dont want to use this way bec I have to automate stopping td-agent wil be like I have to kill process "/opt/td-agent/usr/sbin/td-agent -vvv -c td-agent.conf"

Answer (score 1):

You can change the user and group in the "/lib/systemd/system/td-agent.service" file from:

```
[Service]
User=td-agent
Group=td-agent
```

to

```
[Service]
User=root
Group=root
```

Finally, do a daemon-reload and a service (Fluentd/td-agent) restart

Comment: Is there a way to set this automatically via td-agent api?

Comment: You can use RUN `sudo sed -ir "s/^[#]*\s*User=.*/User=root/" /lib/systemd/system/td-agent.service` to set the User to value to root. Similarly for Group